# jQuery - Iterate JSON, Join The Results and Output as String

Tags: jquery, json, loops

I want to iterate a JSON Object and then join/ merge each result into string.

Here is my codes:

**JSON:**

```
var jsonObj = [ {"tag": "article"}, {"tag": "header"} ]
```

**jQUery:**

```
var json = $.parseJSON(jsonObj);
var element = $.each(json, function(i, val){
    var finder = 'find("' + val.tag + '")';         
    return finder;
});
alert(element);
```

I tried using `.join()` after `$.each()`, like this `$.each(...).join();` but it is returning object.

I also using `.get()`, like this `$.each(...).get().join();` but returning error.

What can I use to join the result returned in each iteration and then merge them and output as a string?

Comment: what is  `'find()'` as a string used for? Are you wanting to invoke as function?

Comment: I want to write it as executable js string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jdgr9dyz/)**

Use `.map()` chained with `.join()` to get the values in a string.

```
var jsonObj = [{"tag": "article"}, {"tag": "header"}]
var json = $.parseJSON(jsonObj);
var element = $.map(json, function(obj){
    var finder = 'find("' + obj.tag + '")';         
    return finder;
}).join(' , ');
console.log(element)
```

Note that `.each()` does not support `.get()`.

Comment: it works... but I can't then use index and `in` inside the iteration... like so:

`var element = $.map(json, function(i, obj){
    var finder = ""; 
    if(json.length - i == json.length) {
     finder += i + " ";
    }
    if("tag" in obj) {
     finder += '$("' + obj.tag + '")';
    }
    return finder;
}).join(' , ');`

Comment: Yes you can, the syntax is a little different for .map() with index. Check this http://jsfiddle.net/jdgr9dyz/1/ . Instead of `function(i, obj)` its `function(obj,i)`

Comment: You beat it once again...!